# CodeIgniter - where and when should I call $this->load->database()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and currently in my project I have several Models, loaded by several Controllers, which need to work with the database.

My question is - can I call `$this->load->database()` in just one place for the entire project, or should I do it in each method in my Models?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `autoload.php` which is located in `/application/config/autoload.php` in which you see 
`$autoload['libraries']` array just add

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database','other_libraries');
```

If your project scope involves the database interaction you should use the `autoload` while including in each function would be a headache for you
Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If only some of your pages require database connectivity you can manually connect to your database by adding this line of code

```
 $this->load->database();
```

in any function where it is needed, or in your class constructor to make the database available globally in that class.

The "auto connect" feature will load and instantiate the database class with every page.just 
add the word 'database' to the library array, as indicated in the following file:

> application/config/autoload.php

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices (that I can think of).

1. If you require it almost everywhere in your project, use the
   `/application/config/autoload.php` file, in which you'll find the
   following statement:

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array();
   ```

   which you can change to

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
   ```

   This is the easiest method, but it does add overhead since the database class will be loaded even when you do not require it.
2. If you find that you need to use it for almost every method *in a particular model* you can call `$this->load->database();` in the constructor of that particular model, for example:

   ```
   class Forums_model extends CI_Model{

      function __construct()
      {
          // Call the parent constructor
          parent::__construct();

          $this->load->database();
      }

      function get_records()
      {
          $this->db->get('table'); 
          //this now works in every method in this model
      }
   }
   ```

   which will make the database class available to every method in that model. This is a more efficient option than the second and not as tedious as the third, probably making it the most balanced option.
3. You can also, of course, choose to load it in every method that requires it using `$this->load->database();` This adds the least overhead, theoretically making it the most efficient. However, doing this is very tedious.

All three will work, it's your choice whether you want it to be easy, or efficient. (My personal recommendation is choice 2)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best of all methods, but since you are beginner.. you just call load data base `$this->load->database()` in that method just above the code where your database related query begins.. just suppose `$this ->load->database();` is exactly the same thing for you as you were using `include_once('connection.php')` this script in you simple php script (without CI).

Comment: That wasn't my question. I was asking if there is a better way than calling it from each function.

Comment: i explained you as a beginner as you mention in your very first line of post

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner but I think you should read my question again before arguing any further.